# How to Fix Undefined Variable $data Error in Laravel Views?

Tags: laravel

Undefined variable `$data`:
[image: error]

But I have declared `$data` on the controller like this:

```
public function coba()
{
    $data = coba::all();

    return view('coba');
}
```

And the view like this

##### `coba.blade.php`

```html
@foreach ($data as $w)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$w->name}} </td>
        <td>{{$w->no}}</td>
        <td>{{$w->fraksi}}</td>
        <td>{{$w->dapil}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Pass the `$data` variable to your view.  `return view('coba', ['data' => $data]);`. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#displaying-data

Comment: Route::get('/coba', function () {
    return view('coba' ,['data' => $data]);
}); like this?? its not working

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful... Yes, that is the correct syntax to send `$data` to the front-end. When you use that code, what is happening? _Why_ is it not working? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76324947/edit) with more details

Comment: when adding the syntax you gave, the problem goes to web.php not to the view

Comment: Did you forget `$data = coba::all();` before trying to do `return view('coba', ['data' => $data]);`? Why would you delete that line? `Route::get('/coba', function () { $data = coba::all(); return view('coba', ['data' => $data]); });`

Comment: here I am trying to retrieve data in the database

Comment: I know, but you need to define the variable `$data` before using it via `['data' => $data]`... IGP did not mean delete your original code, but modify the `return` line from what you had to what actually works... Please brush up on your basic PHP syntax.

Comment: can you help me through teamviewer??

Comment: No, see my comment on the total syntax, and follow the documentation: `Route::get('/coba', function () { $data = coba::all(); return view('coba', ['data' => $data]); });`

Comment: fyi, you don't use a controller if you return the view from your route. Not sure why you changed that

Comment: oh ya, here I use  open admin for the backend is that not a problem??

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering is due to the missing variable `$data` in the `return view('coba');` statement of your controller.

To fix this, you need to pass the `$data` variable to the view so that it is accessible within the blade template.

```
public function coba()
{
    $data = coba::all();

    return view('coba', ['data' => $data]);
}
```